# dipole field on axis twice the field on perpendicular bisector

Tags: electric-fields, coulombs-law, dipole

Why is the dipole field on axis twice the field on perpendicular bisector?
**For the perpendicular bisector:**
Lets assume -q is right from of the origin and +q is left from the origin, both a distance a from the origin.
The electric field at a point on the y-axis(on the perpendicular bisector of the dipole) is
$$\vec E = {\vec E_+ + \vec E_-} = {kq\over(\sqrt{a^2+y^2})^2}{a\hat i-(-a\hat i)\over\sqrt{a^2+y^2}}={2akq\over(a^2+y^2)^{\frac32}\hat i}$$
$$\text{when }y>>a:\quad{{2akq\over y^3}\hat i}$$
$$\text{in terms of electric dipole moment }p=2aq:\quad{{kp\over y^3}\hat i}$$
For the electric field on the dipole's axis, the value my book gives for x>>a is twice the dipole field on the perpendicular bisector:
$${2kp\over x^3}\hat i$$
But they really don't explain why. I tried to derive it with no luck. Why is it twice the other value? Can you help me derive it?
Thank you already

Comment: What is a "perpendicular bisector" here?

Comment: http://www.pstcc.edu/departments/natural_behavioral_sciences/Web%20Physics/D1916.gif

Comment: though in this picture the dipole lies vertically while in my example it lies horizontally with the origin being it's center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general equation for electric field due to dipole at a point is KP/R^3[(1+3cos^2(thetha)]^1/2. When (thetha=90 it is equitorial line and when (theta=0) it is axial line from the above equation we get the required results ie KP/R^3 and 2KP/R^3

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a source that explains the term sqrt(1+3cos(theta)^2) ?

Comment: A source in the sense I didn't get u could u plz be a bit comprehensive I mean clear

Comment: A website that explains why

Comment: Gimme 15 min I'll upload a pic

Comment: your images didn't upload. there's nothing to see

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rbqs.jpg

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hO0OK.jpg